# Python Celery как он поведет себя при использовании с внешним брокером

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

пытаюсь разобраться в Celery (с брокером rabbitmq), чтобы понять, стоит ли использовать его для моих проектов.
Допустим есть периодический таск, который записывает в файл каждые 10 секунд время:

```
from celery import Celery
from datetime import datetime

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://name:password@ip/host')

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s(), name='add every 10')

@app.task
def test():
    f = open('/home/CeleryApp/App/result.txt', 'a')
    f.write(str(datetime.now()))
    f.close()
```

Например я создал воркера на своем личном ПК (А) и запустил этот таск, при этом сам брокер будет находится на отдельном сервере (Б).

Вопрос: Куда в таком случае запишется файл? На пк А или Б?

Мне непонятен этот момент, так как я совершенно не понимаю, каким образом он может выполнять мои задачи в каком-то другом месте. А если в таске будет подключение к базе данных? Сможет ли оно выполнить подключение к БД и внести туда какие-то изменения? Т.к. в основном я хочу ставить таски связанные с БД.

P.S. возможно я ошибаюсь на фундаментальном уровне, поэтому прошу прояснить.